# Excel VBA To Call SQL Stored Procedure (Date parameter - No results!)

Tags: sql-server, excel, adodb, vba

I finally got this code working by adding `Set NOCOUNT ON` in my stored procedure.  I'm having trouble getting results when I use dates as parameters though.

Code as below -

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.RecordSet

'''Clear extract area'''
Worksheets("Extract").UsedRange.Delete

'''Log into SQL Server'''
con.Open "Provider = SQLOLEDB;" & _
         "Data Source = MySource;" & _
         "Initial Catalog = MyDatabase;" & _
         "User ID = MyUser;" & _
         "Password = MyPassword;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con

'''Set up parameters for stored procedure'''
'cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("lot", adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, Range("C4"))

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("startDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, Range("C2"))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("endDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, Range("C3"))

'adDBTimeStamp

cmd.CommandText = "DB.MyStoredProc"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

Set WSP1 = Worksheets("Extract")
WSP1.Activate
If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

As I said, just using the first parameter by itself, I get results pasted into my Worksheet as expected.  When I comment that line out and try to run with the two date parameters I get nothing.

The code runs without error but shows an empty worksheet.  I've got a feeling this has something to do with date formatting but am unsure how to input the dates into SQL as it needs them.

Could somebody help please?

**---Update---**
I've tried setting my parameters like this -

```
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("startDate", adDate, adParamInput)
        cmd.Parameters.Append prm
        cmd.Parameters("startDate").Value = "2017-07-17"

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("endDate", adDate, adParamInput)
        cmd.Parameters.Append prm
        cmd.Parameters("endDate").Value = "2017-07-19"
```

But Excel VBA still appears to be sending date through in dd/mm/yyyy format!

**---Update2---**

As per @avb's answer I have changed my code to include the following -

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "exec DB.myStoredProc '__dateParameter1__', '__dateParameter2__' ;"
sql = Replace(sql, "__dateParameter1__", Format(Range("C2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
sql = Replace(sql, "__dateParameter2__", Format(Range("C3").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd"))

cmd.CommandText = sql
Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

This appears to pass the date values in the correct format, but still returns an empty recordset.  As before, testing the same string with the single value VarChar works fine.  It's just when I use the 2 date parameters.

*Working SQL query generated by SSMS when clicking 'Execute' in menu -*

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [DB].[myStoredProc]
        @startDate = N'2017-07-20'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

*Working query copied from VBA (pulls single batch number)*

```
exec DB.myStoredProc '4238176' ;
```

*Non-working query from VBA (attempting to pull all batches after this date)*

```
exec DB.myStoredProc '2017-07-20' ;
```

Comment: Have you tested the SP, with params, in SSMS?

Comment: Yup.  Inputting the parameters as yyyy-mm-dd returns results.  I'm just not sure how I can force the VBA to pass the Date value in that format in ADODB (I think that's the issue).

Comment: You can test the theory by passing hard-coded params.  If that fixes use the VBA [format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) to ensure passed as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Not sure how to hard-code this.  Tried #2017-07-17# but it just auto-corrects to vba format.

Comment: Also, the format function converts it to a string right? I tried to nest that into CDate but still didn't work.

Comment: format method change data to  text. Else use  Columns("c").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: and  Worksheets("Extract").UsedRange.clearcontents is more effective than Worksheets("Extract").UsedRange.Delete

Comment: try copying your final sql variable value and run it SSMS

Comment: Still nothing @avb. It displays the field headers but no row data.  I even tried changing the SP to only require 1 date parameter to rule that out.  Also tried playing with the SQL query to convert the string date to an SQL date.  No data returned...

Comment: So, how the query copied from vba differs from working one? could you paste both?

Comment: @avb Updated again.

Comment: I think I may have done it...

Comment: this is not a date in your working code!

Comment: No.  But the SSMS generated code is a date.  The VBA working code is just to illustrate that it did work with varchar but not with a date parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149799/discussion-between-avb-and-jamsandwich).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Range("C2")` in CreateParameter with
`Format(Range("C2").Value, "yyyymmdd")`

Date format **yyyymmdd** is the only one that is always recognizable to sql server, disregarding your locale.

constructing sql statement without using parameters:

```
Dim sql As String  
sql = "exec DB.MyStoredProc '__dateParameter__' ;"
sql = Replace(sql, "__dateParameter__", Format(Range("C2").Value, "yyyymmdd"))

cmd.CommandText = sql
Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

Finally it appeared stored procedure had first, optional parameter being some other value than date, so the correct answer is:

```
Dim sql As String  
sql = "exec DB.MyStoredProc null, '__dateParameter__' ;"
sql = Replace(sql, "__dateParameter__", Format(Range("C2").Value, "yyyymmdd"))

cmd.CommandText = sql
Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't produce an error.  But I still don't get any values returned.

Comment: When I step through the code and mouse over one of these parameters it still shows the date in it's original excel format rather than this format style.  That's frustrating

Comment: Another way to do this is (I always do it this way) is to construct whole query string to be executed with VBA and then assign it to `.CommandText`

Comment: I've done similar with previous queries but never with a stored procedure taking parameters.  No amount of searching has showed me an example of somebody doing this within a string, do you think it's doable?  I'm going to look into setting the parameters as strings in the SP and converting within SQL.

Comment: Surely it is, just `"exec DB.MyStoredProc 'parm1', 'parm2', 'parmN'"` and you have it

Comment: Bah!  I changed the parameters in the SP to be VarChar. Still works in SSMS.  Use VBA to pass them in as a string and use CAST to convert in the SP and still getting blanks sheet...

Comment: ...I'll look into that

Comment: @Jamsandwich, do it my way and you will be able to see exact statement executed, step thru your code, ask for it in Immediate window and run in ssms to check

Comment: Forgive me @avb. I'm struggling to fit this into the larger VBA code.  Is there any chance you could provide a sample?

Comment: Perfect.  Again @avb thank you so much for the help.  You pointed me in all the right directions

Answer (score 0):

Setting your datetime data columns numberformat like this.

```
Set WSP1 = Worksheets("Extract")
With WSP1
If rs.EOF = False Then .Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    .Columns("c").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" '<~~~ datetime data column c
End With
```

Comment: Hi @Dy.Lee.  This doesn't seem to have made any difference.  I'm really confused about why my VBA won't work.